# node vk bot api, ошибка в функции с привязкой к глобальному контексту

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу вк-бота с использованием node vk bot api, хочу сделать функцию ответа на команду, т.к. есть четыре команды, на которые нужен одинаковый ответ и функцией это сделать будет короче, чем вставлять 4 раза 1 и тот же кусок кода. Код:

```js
function sendManul() {

 console.log('Бот получил команду.')

 var manul = randomInteger(1, 14);
 
 sleep(1000)

 if(manul == 1) {
  ctx.reply('Оригинальная версия:', 'video-195682710_456239018')
  console.log('Отправлена оригинальная версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 2) {
  ctx.reply('Версия "спокойной ночи":', 'video-195682710_456239019')
  console.log('Отправлена СН-версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 3) {
  ctx.reply('Версия в перемотке:', 'video-195682710_456239020')
  console.log('Отправлена версия в перемотке.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 4) {
  ctx.reply('Украинская версия:', 'video-195682710_456239021')
  console.log('Отправлена украинская версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 5) {
  ctx.reply('Польская версия:', 'video-195682710_456239022')
  console.log('Отправлена польская версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 6) {
  ctx.reply('Английская версия:', 'video-195682710_456239023')
  console.log('Отправлена английская версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 7) {
  ctx.reply('Японская версия:', 'video-195682710_456239024')
  console.log('Отправлена японская версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 8) {
  ctx.reply('Немецкая версия:', 'video-195682710_456239025')
  console.log('Отправлена немецкая версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 9) {
  ctx.reply('Французская версия:', 'video-195682710_456239026')
  console.log('Отправлена французская версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 10) {
  ctx.reply('Китайская версия:', 'video-195682710_456239027')
  console.log('Отправлена китайская версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 11) {
  ctx.reply('Bassboosted-версия:', 'video-195682710_456239028')
  console.log('Отправлена bassboosted-версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 12) {
  ctx.reply('Remastered украинская версия:', 'video-195682710_456239029')
  console.log('Отправлена Remastered украинская версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 13) {
  ctx.reply('Новогодняя версия:', 'video-195682710_456239030')
  console.log('Отправлена НГ-версия.')
  console.log(' ')
 } else if(manul == 14) {
  ctx.reply('Версия на разных языках:', 'video-195682710_456239031')
  console.log('Отправлена версия на разных языках.')
  console.log('')
 }

}

bot.command('манул', (ctx) => {
 sendManul.call(global);

})

bot.command('vfyek', (ctx) => {
 sendManul.call(global);
})

bot.command('manul', (ctx) => {
 sendManul.call(global);

})

bot.command('ьфтгд', (ctx) => {
 sendManul.call(global);
})
```

Я думаю тут понятно, что я хочу сделать: при 4х запросах должен выполняться 1 и тот же код. Выдает эррорку (node:8007) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reply' of undefined, т.е. оно не может найти метод reply, встроенный в вк апи. вроде указал глобальный контекст при вызове функции, не знаю, куда и как теперь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function foo(ctx) {
    ...
    ctx.reply(...)
}

...

bot.command('bar', foo)
// или
bot.command('bar' (ctx) => foo(ctx))
// или
bot.command('bar', (ctx) => { foo(ctx) })
```

Вы не передавали `ctx` в функцию, отчего и была ошибка, что `ctx` - undefined.